# ¿Por qué mis archivos model aparecen undefinied?

Tags: angular, typescript, model, undefined, type

Cree un archivo model ts en mi proyecto de angular y al principio cuando lo llamaba en el constructor este funcionaba correctamente, pero ahora cada vez que intento llamarlo me dices que esta undefinied
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
constructor(
private _formBuild: FormBuilder,
private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, 
private _route: Router,
private _storageService: StorageService,
private _userService: UserService,
private _netPayService: NetPayService,
private _chargeData : chargeData,
private _tokenData: tokenData)
```

El model chargeData y todos los demas model los tengo con esta sintaxis:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {billingData} from '../models/billingData.model';

//@Injectable()

export class chargeData {
    description: "Cargo de prueba";
    source: string;
    paymentMethod: "card";
    amount: 300;
    currency: "MXN";
    billing: billingData;
    redirect3dsUri: "https://netpay.mx";
  }
```

Esta es la clase billingData que estoy mandando a llamer en la clase chargeData:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

//@Injectable()

export class billingData{
    firstName: "John";
    lastName: "Doe";
    email: "accept@netpay.com.mx";
    phone: "1234567890";
    address: {
      city: "Panuco";
      country: "MX";
      postalCode: "93994";
      state: "Veracruz";
      street1: "Calle";
      street2: "Centro"
    };
    merchantReferenceCode: '12345678'
  }
```

Comment: ¿Te has dado cuenta de que el error hace referencia a una propiedad que no está presente en ningún lado en el código que has pegado?

Comment: de hecho esta en el otro archivo ts que estoy mandando a llamar en la clase billingData